# Verificar varias opciones sin repetir

Tags: java

Imaginad lo siguiente que tengo que verificar las siguientes entradas:

- Chica sea Rubia
- Chica2 sea Morena
- Tenga 18 años
- sea de Madrid

Tengo las siguientes variables

```
String chica;
String chica2;
String ciudad;
Integer edad;
```

Y esta línea de código para verificar si es rubia.

```
if ( chica.equalsIgnoreCase("rubia") {
    //verifica que es cierto..
```

¿Cómo hago para que siga verificando el resto de datos? ¿Y si alguna de las siguientes es incorrecta, que solo me diga la que es incorrecta?

Es decir podría hacer esto:

```
if (chica.equalsIgnoreCase("rubia")
    && ciudad.equals("Madrid") ...
```

Pero necesito ir poco a poco verificando una por una. Y que no se repita ningún dato. Es decir si chica1 es rubia chica2 tiene que ser Morena.

Pero por ejemplo si chica1 es morena entonces la chica2 puede ser rubia. La idea es que los colores de pelo sean diferentes, nunca del mismo color.

Comment: Hola @Montse. Acabo de editar tu pregunta. Por favor comprueba que realmente refleje lo que deseas preguntar. De lo contrario, edítalo para que se pueda comprender mejor lo que estás haciendo. Asimismo, eliminé la parte de que utilizas WindowsBuilder porque eso se asocia a la parte visual mientras que tu duda es sobre código Java.

Comment: Asimismo, redacta un título que resuma tu pregunta lo más posible, de manera que tenga coherencia con el contenido de la pregunta.

Comment: Si me ha ido genial, me has aclarado mucho. Voy a modificar.

Acabado de añadir un poco más de info! gracias!

Comment: quizas me equivoque, ademas de que es algo confuso, puedo entender como esta comparando el color de pelo para cada chica, pero con los datos que muestras, por ejemplo en ciudad como comparas que una chica sea de una cidad determinada y la otra no, lo mismo para la edad, creo que tiene o puedes crear una clase por ejemplo que tenga la variables que comentas ej.  String colorPelo, String nombreCiudad, . edad, ->

Comment: -> y creas los objetos y asignas las variables y luego accedes a los objetos para comparar las variables por ejemplo la ciudad de una con la de la otra o lo que quieras, porque como se relaciona chica1 con la variable ciudad y como sabes que pertenece a una y no a la otra, espero te ayude. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel voy a editarlo!

Comment: @AngelAngel he echo una nueva pregunta que creo que se verá mas clara.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero validamos que el valor de chica y chica2 sean diferentes para proseguir y validar los demás datos.

```
//Ingresa si el valor de chica y chica2 son diferentes.
if (!chica.equalsIgnoreCase(chica2)) {
}
```

Con la anterior validación, ya verificamos que el valor de chica y chica2 sean diferentes. Una vez ingrese al anterior código se pueden verificar los demás datos. Por ejemplo: una vez encuentre el primer dato erróneo lo retorne.

```
//Ingresa si el valor de chica y chica2 son diferentes.
if (!chica.equalsIgnoreCase(chica2)) {

} else {
    //Vamos a verificar cual fue el error
    String error = (chica.equalsIgnoreCase("Rubia"))?"chica2":"chica";
    return error;
}
```

Con la anterior validación, en caso que ambos valores de chica y chica2 sean iguales irán al else, si chica es Rubia, me retornara chica2 como error o si chica es Morena, me retorna chica como error(Según las entradas el valor de chica debe ser Rubia). Ahora verificaremos las demás entradas.

```
//Entrara si el valor de chica y chica2 son diferentes
if (!chica.equalsIgnoreCase(chica2)) {
    //Si la ciudad es diferente a Madrid retornara "ciudad" como error
    if(!ciudad.equalsIgnoreCase("Madrid"))
        return "ciudad";
    //Si la edad es != 18 retornara "edad" como error
    else if(edad != 18)
        return "edad";
} else {
    //Vamos a verificar cual fue el error
    String error = (chica.equalsIgnoreCase("Rubia"))?"chica2":"chica";
    return error;
}
```

Listo. Me retorna el primer error que encuentre en la validaciones. Por ejemplo si el valor de chica y chica2 son diferentes y ciudad no es Madrid me retornara como error ciudad. Ahora bien, puede crear una función que me retorne un String para saber cual fue el primer error que encontró, o puede retornar un Array o un String que concatene los errores que se encuentren. A continuación la función que retorna el primer error que encuentre.

```
public String getPrimerError(String chica,String chica2,String ciudad, Integer edad){
    String error = "";
    //Entrara si el valor de chica y chica2 son diferentes
    if (!chica.equalsIgnoreCase(chica2)) {
        //Si la ciudad es diferente a Madrid retornara "ciudad" como error
        if(!ciudad.equalsIgnoreCase("Madrid"))
            return "ciudad";
        //Si la edad es != 18 retornara "edad" como error
        else if(edad != 18)
            return "edad";
    } else {
        //Vamos a verificar cual fue el error
        error = (chica.equalsIgnoreCase("Rubia"))?"chica2":"chica";
    }
    return error;
}
```

Si el retorno de la anterior función es "", es porque no hubo ni un error. Espero esto te ayude.

Comment: Hola Gustavo, en el problema no importa el color de pelo, si chica1 y 2 tienen el mismo color, el mensaje de error debería ser "chica1 y 2 tienen el mimso color", o algo similar, la última verificación no tiene sentido.

Comment: gracias!!!! Ahora ya sé como hacerlo!